# How to disable GNOME 3.26.1 snapped windows coupling

Tags: gnome-shell

So I have noticed that when windows are snapped in Gnome they act as if they are one window when focused on. In other words, if I have a terminal partially on top of two snapped windows, like this:[Example situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9gxI.png)

If I click on any of the two snapped windows to bring it into focus, both windows will be brought into focus (both firefox and sublime in the example above). How do I disable this behavior? I want only the window that I clicked to be brought into focus.

Comment: Your question is older than the other, but I think the other one has an answer that covers both.